# Getting error when saving worksheet in ClosedXML.Excel 'Error in implicit conversion. Cannot convert null object'

Tags: excel, vb.net, closedxml

I'm getting error when running the below code ('Error in implicit conversion. Cannot convert null object.') I'm using ClosedXML.Excel for writing excel file (VB.NET).

This code is working for uploading some of the excel files, but it is throwing the above error while uploading another excel file. Any idea about this error please?

Thanks in advance

'''

```
    Dim dt As New DataTable()
    dt.Columns.Add("ColumnName")
    dt.Columns.Add("FieldValue")

    For Each column As IXLColumn In workSheet.Columns()
        If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(column.Cell(rowNumber).Value.ToString()) Then
            dt.Rows.Add()
            dt.Rows(dt.Rows.Count - 1)(0) = column.Cell(rowNumber).Address.ColumnLetter.ToString()
            dt.Rows(dt.Rows.Count - 1)(1) = column.Cell(rowNumber).Value.ToString()
        End If
    Next
    
    Using workBook As New XLWorkbook(TemplateFileUpload.PostedFile.InputStream)
        Dim workSheet As IXLWorksheet = workBook.Worksheet("Template")
        Dim row As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(templateStartRow)
        Dim dtTemplateColumnFields As DataTable = dt 'Getting field name and database name combinations into array

        For Each dtRow As DataRow In dtProducts.Rows
            For Each item As DataRow In dtTemplateColumnFields.Rows
                If dtRow.Table.Columns.Contains(item(1)) Then
                    workSheet.Cell(row, item(0).ToString()).Value = dtRow(item(1))
                End If
            Next
            row = row + 1
        Next '99 rows and 193 columns is there in worksheet

    Using stream As New MemoryStream()
        workBook.SaveAs(stream) 'Error is throwing in this line
        stream.Position = 0
        Response.Clear()
        Response.Buffer = True
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + TemplateFileUpload.PostedFile.FileName)
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
        Response.BinaryWrite(stream.ToArray())
        Response.End()
    End Using
        labelMessage.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green
        labelMessage.Visible = True
    End Using
```

'''

Comment: It's not clear what you are attempting to do. What is `TemplateFileUpload.PostedFile.InputStream`? Try adding `If wbook Is Nothing Then Response.Write("wbook is null") End If` before `Using stream As New MemoryStream()`

Comment: @user9938 The workbook is not null (it contains a Worksheet("Template") with 99 rows and 193 columns) and TemplateFileUpload is a fileupload control and TemplateFileUpload.PostedFile.InputStream is the inputstream of the posted file. I'm not able to understand which object is null :S